# Trying to save canvas data, file end up empty

Tags: javascript, ajax, canvas

I am trying to upload from a canvas to a server with ajax but everytime I seem to be getting an empty image file of 879 bytes. I am not sure where I am going wrong. If somebody could have a look it would be most appreciated.

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener("change",function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var output = document.getElementById('test');
  reader.onload = function () {
    var data = this.result;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = data;
    img.onload = function() {
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
output.innerHTML = 'width: ' + img.width + '\n' + 'height: ' + img.height;
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    };
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Ajax below

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "upload_images.php",
    data: { canvasData:canvasData },
    success:function() {
    }
});

```
$upload_dir = 'uploads/';  //implement this function yourself
$img = $_POST['canvasData'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = $upload_dir."image_name.png";
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
header('Location: '.$_POST['return_url']);
```

Comment: you are calling `toDataURL` out of your callback, so it runs before the image have been drawn to it...

Comment: You are not waiting for the onload to run and thus output an empty canvas. JS is single threaded and the onload will not fire until you have exited the current execution . Add the toDataURL to the end of the onload function

Answer (score 0):

Awseome, all solved...
Following your comments I moved the toDataUrl within the unload as well the ajax upload and all good. Thanks again.